# How to fork an additional branch from upstream in GitHub, through GitHub web interface? (→not by a linux command line)

Tags: github, fork

I've forked the `master` branch only of an open-source project.
*GitHub* allows me to re-synchronize my forked branch using its web interface conveniently.

But I need to take another branch from the original project: `branch-3.5`, to work on it.
In terms of bash command lines, it's:

```bash
git remote add upstream https://github.com/original_project
git fetch --all
git checkout branch-3.5
```

But it's not these commands that I want to run.

I'm willing to ask, through *GitHub* web interface, the repatriation of the `branch-3.5` on my fork first,
and then, from my command line (while in my fork), do a simple `git checkout branch-3.5` to get it.

Summarizing:

Currently, I have on my fork only the `master` branch available with its *Sync fork* option

[image]

and I would like to repatriate a second branch from the source project,
**before** typing any command line on my own computer terminal.

How is it possible through *GitHub* web interface?

---

Yet, I've destroyed my fork, and recreated one asking for `all the branches` to be forked, and not `master` only, but it's not a nice solution: when a new branch will appear, I'll be in front of the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Click on the `main` branch hyperlink

[image: main branch - step 1]

##### Then click `New Branch`

[image: main branch - step 2]

##### Then select the source repository

[image: main branch - step 3]

##### Then select the branch you want to add

[image: new branch - step 4]

##### Then you can name the branch whatever you want, usually this would be the same as the upstream branch

[image: new branch - step 5]

##### Then `Create New Branch`

##### Finally, in your local:

- fetch the new branch
- checkout the branch
- push the new branch to your fork with `-u` to "track this branch"
  You can add a remote later if you want to track the remote.

```bash
git fetch origin
git checkout <new-branch-name>
git push -u origin <new-branch-name>
```